# HP ALM | REST API Error ALM-E10004: Failed to load project?

Tags: api, rest, alm, hp-alm

I am using HP ALM Version 11.52.809.

After authenticating, I'm trying to fetch the list of domains using the following REST-API :

```
http://19.17.16.69:7424/qcbin/rest/domains
```

I am receiving the following error :

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /qcbin/rest/domains. Reason:

    ALM-E10004: Failed to load project 'null' from domain 'null'.
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hp.alm.platform.directory.CProjectsDirectory.getItem(CProjectsDirectory.java:79)
    wrapped in com.hp.alm.platform.siteadmin.session.ProjectDoesNotExisatException: ALM-E10004: Failed to load project 'null' from domain 'null'.
at com.hp.alm.platform.directory.CProjectsDirectory.getItem(CProjectsDirectory.java:125)
at org.hp.qc.impl.customization.CustomizationServiceImpl.getCustomization(CustomizationServiceImpl.java:73)
at org.hp.qc.impl.customization.CustomizationServiceImpl.getDefaultCustomization(CustomizationServiceImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor173.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
at org.hp.qc.impl.aspects.cache.ReturnValueCachingAspect$CacheResult.get(ReturnValueCachingAspect.java:228)
at org.hp.qc.impl.aspects.cache.ReturnValueCachingAspect.invoke(ReturnValueCachingAspect.java:107)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor155.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy63.getDefaultCustomization(Unknown Source)
at org.hp.qc.impl.customization.CustomizationServiceImpl.find(CustomizationServiceImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy63.find(Unknown Source)
at org.hp.qc.impl.services.sessionmanagement.AuthenticationImpl.getPrincipal(AuthenticationImpl.java:73)
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.createSecurityContext(SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.java:263)
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.creatSecurityContextForNonExistingUser(SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.java:239)
at com.hp.sw.bto.ast.security.lwsso.authenticator.springSecurity.SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurity2LWSSOIntegrationFilter.java:172)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.authentication.QCSpringSecurity2lwssoIntegrationFilter.doFilter(QCSpringSecurity2lwssoIntegrationFilter.java:29)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.sessionmanagement.ImplicitSessionFilter.doFilter(ImplicitSessionFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.authentication.QC2SpringIntegrationFilter.LWSSO2SpringSecurityIntegrationFilterDoFilter(QC2SpringIntegrationFilter.java:350)
at org.hp.qc.web.restapi.authentication.QC2SpringIntegrationFilter.doFilter(QC2SpringIntegrationFilter.java:71)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
```

What is causing this error? Is there is any setting or privilege which needs to be done on ALM Side?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does your user assigned to any project?

Comment: Yes User is assigned to a project.

Comment: And calls to different APIs works fine (e.g. /rest/domains/<domain>/projects/<proj>/customization/entities/test-instance)? I've tried to call qcbin/rest/domains on ALM 12.5 and it works fine. So maybe there is an issue with your domain/project or a bug in ALM 11.52

Comment: This error is coming with one or two users of the project, but rest of other users on the same project are able to fetch the domains

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code, one can only guess what has been done. With that said, here is the documentation from Microfocus which will be helpful.

Domains:
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST_API_Tech_Preview/REST/domains.html?Highlight=domain

Projects:
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST_API_Tech_Preview/REST/projects.html

When asking question please provide the code that you have tried, even if its a API request, it matters how you authenticate, whether the contentType and other header information has been passed correctly or not. So, update your question with some real code.

Comment: I'm Using Postman Client for this API Request.